# Calling a Java Method from Visual Basic 6

Tags: java, vb6

I need to use a java class from visual basic 6. 
How should I declare the java class? 
I need to recieve 4 Strings, how do I recieve them?
How do I call this class from Visual Basic 6?
How should I handle the return value?

As you realize I am quite new with this and would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure there is a better way, but you can call the Java program on the command line

```
java -cp {class-path} TheNameOfYourClass arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
```

You can get the return value from the output of the program.

e.g.

```
class TheNameOfYourClass {
    public static void mains(String... args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
    }
}
```

if you run with `arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4` it will print

```
[arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4]
```

Comment: Ok thats a good idea. My question now is, how could I handle the return value? I need my java class to return to visual basic a String.

Comment: Can VB capture the output of a program as a String? e.g. could you take the `echo Hello` and get a String `Hello`?

Comment: Is it possible to redirect the java output to a file and then read the file? `java -cp {class-path} TheNameOfYourClass arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 > output.txt`